# How to use 'this' in an angular non-class controller in coffeescript:

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

I'm curious as to why the below does not work, which I assume is something I don't understand about coffeescript:

```js
angular.module('clientApp')
  .controller 'FoobarCtrl', ($scope) ->

    console.log "Foobar controller"

    $scope.content = "message from foobar"

    @output = () ->
        return "returned message from coffee controller"
```

I thought the above would be the equivalent of:

```js
angular.module('clientApp')
  .controller('FoobazCtrl', function ($scope) {

    console.log( "Foobar controller" )

    $scope.content = "message from foobar";

    this.output = function(){ 
        return("returned message from coffee controller");
    }

  });
```

But it doesn't seem to be. Can anyone tell me where it's gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent would be:

```
angular.module("clientApp").controller "FoobazCtrl", ($scope) ->
  console.log "Foobar controller"
  $scope.content = "message from foobar"
  @output = ->
    "returned message from coffee controller"

  return
```

Your coffescript code is generating this javascript:

```
angular.module('clientApp').controller('FoobarCtrl', function($scope) {
  console.log("Foobar controller");
  $scope.content = "message from foobar";
  return this.output = function() {
    return "returned message from coffee controller";
  };
});
```